# Retrieve rows from database where four fields have two values

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have a table names results with four fields where each is a foreign key to a names table.  The names table includes the person's name, birthdate and sex.  I need to write a query that will retrieve all results when two people are male and two are female.

**results Table**

- person1 int
- person2 int
- person3 int
- person4 int

**names Table**

- person_id int
- firstname varchar
- lastname varchar
- middlename varchar
- birthdate date
- sex char   <-- possible values are m or f

My query looks like this so far

```
SELECT 
  p1.firstname,p1.lastname,p1.middlename,p1.birthdate,p1.sex,
  p2.firstname,p2.lastname,p2.middlename,p2.birthdate,p2.sex,
  p3.firstname,p3.lastname,p3.middlename,p3.birthdate,p3.sex,
  p4.firstname,p4.lastname,p4.middlename,p4.birthdate,p4.sex
FROM
 ((((results r LEFT JOIN names p1 ON p1.person_id=r.person1)
 LEFT JOIN
  results r LEFT JOIN names p2 ON p2.person_id=r.person2)
 LEFT JOIN
  results r LEFT JOIN names p3 ON p3.person_id=r.person3)
LEFT JOIN
  results r LEFT JOIN names p4 ON p4.person_id=r.person4)
```

What do I need to do to retrieve all rows where there are two males and two females?  I have tried google to find other examples but haven't found anything yet.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Comment: @strawberry, the results table contains the results of relay events where there are four competitors.  I'm not sure how this could have been designed differently, but I'm always open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can get rid of all the parentheses in the `from` clause.  You are not using MS Access, so don't make your query look like you are using it.

Second, the `left join`s can be `inner join`s.  You require a match to get the genders and all four are needed for all your conditions.

Third, you simply need to count the number of males and females.  Using your query, that is a bit tricky, but you can do it with an exhaustive set of `and` and `or` comparisons.  Or using complicated `case` logic. Or, use the string concatenation method:

```
where concat(p1.sex, p2.sex, p3.sex, p4.sex) in ('MMFF', 'MFMF', 'MFFM', 'FMMF', 'FMFM', 'FFMM')
```

Comment: This is kind of where I was heading at first.  I was thinking there was something more elegant, but sometimes brute force is what's needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (p1.sex = 'M' + p2.sex = 'M' + p3.sex = 'M' + p4.sex = 'M') = 2
```

Comment: I like this. I'll give it a try tonight when I have computer time.